# JavaScript Async/Await user input with addEventListerner

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, addeventlistener

This seems to be such a simple problem, and yet I'm really struggling to find any information about this so I'm hoping some of you might be able to guide me...

I'm currently building a vanilla javascript board game to expand my skills. It's essentially a turn based game that awaits user input such as clicking the dice or the a piece before moving on to the next step within the turn. I originally tried this just by jumping from one function to the next within the event listener's callback and it worked, however I wanted to try and simplify it and make a more linear by using ES6 async/await.

I've used async/await many many times for fetching data, and it works great, and I'm sure I've heard of people using it to await user input, but I can't seem to get it working in this case. I'm trying to archieve something like this:

```
async function playerTurn() {

  const rollValue = await dice.addEventListener('click', () => rollDice()); 
  renderDice(rollValue);
  const targetPiece = await board.addEventListener('click', (e) => selectPiece(e)); 
  movePiece(targetPiece);

  // so on and so forth...
}
```

However, it just return undefined straight away. I'd love to know if this is just something I'm doing wrong, or if this is simply not possible to use async/await with event listeners? If any of you have any other alternative suggestions as to how to nicely manage a turn by turn game of this style any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `addEventListener` returns undefined, not a promise as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) ... async/await doesn't magically wait for just any asynchronous code  ... it's specifically used for `Promise`s

Comment: You can use, with the right code, async/await with event listeners, however, it's unlikely that you want to. Since promises resolve ONCE, but events can trigger more than once

Comment: @JaromandaX ah that makes total sense! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You'll need to make a `new Promise` for the (single) next click event.

Comment: @JaromandaX I did think about the multiple event triggers, but I figured I could remove the event listener after the event was triggered, and then add it again on the next turn. Do you happen to have any examples of how I would get a event listener to indirectly return a Promise?

Comment: The correct design would be to remove the event listeners out of `playerTurn` and call `playerTurn` after the last player activity. So have `selectPiece` call `playerTurn`. You will need a state logic in each of your event listeners to know when they are valid (eg: return if it is not yet time for player to click a piece on the board)

Comment: Note: Software like Microsoft Word and Google Chrome (basically any GUI software) are designed the way I described above. Word does not have a function that waits for user to open a file, type characters into the document and save the file. Instead opening the file is one separate function tied to the open menu, typing characters is a different function which modifies the file object and saving the file is a separate function that is tied to the save menu. You need to think like this when programming GUI apps in any language: C++, Java etc. not just javascript.

Comment: there's always the `once` option, so you don't have to explicitly remove the event listener once it fires

Comment: @slebetman So just double checking I understand, you're saying that rather than adding/removing the event listeners within the playerTurn() function, I would just keep the event listerners active throughout the game and return a different value based on what the current game state is?

Comment: Not adding/removing - that can get buggy if there is an error. Instead keep a state machine. Inside the `selectPiece()` function check `if (player.state === SELECT_PIECE)`. Keep modifying `player.state`. Basically that one variable is what your `playerTurn` function tries to sequence.

Comment: @slebetman If you have many buttons to choose from, yes, you'd use an event-driven GUI design. However, for linear asynchronous flow like modal dialogs or wizards, `async`/`await` can work quite well (assuming it [supports cancellation](https://vorpus.org/blog/timeouts-and-cancellation-for-humans/)) - this is basically analogous to a state machine.

Comment: @Bergi From the description it looks like the OP is doing a board game - like Monopoly  or Snakes & Ladders. For the OP's use case **I personally** would 100% recommend an event-driven design

Comment: @slebetman Actually I think board games with their usually simple, turn-based, step-by-step game algorithms are a perfect fit for `async`/`await` style. The individual building blocks, and the global app menus, would of course be event-driven.